# Selenium IE driver

Tags: selenium

whenever am running the below code its showing the Error massage And its not closing the browser also :-

Code:-

```
String service = "C:\\Users\\arvind\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.52.2\\IEDriverServer.exe";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", service);
            InternetExplorerDriver  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.get("https://in.mail.yahoo.com/?.intl=in&.lang=en-IN");
            System.out.println("successful");
            driver.quit();
```

Result:

```
First Time execution:-
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.52.2.0
Listening on port 38241
Only local connections are allowed
successful



Second Time execution:-
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.52.2.0
Listening on port 21589
Only local connections are allowed
successful
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the first part of your question, the `Only local connections are allowed` message is **not** an error.

If you look at the Driver [source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a667cd00252d032b4df26a60d7b2d07911ed1d85/cpp/iedriverserver/IEDriverServer.cpp#L320), that message is written-out if 'silent' mode is off, and no IP whitelist entries have been set. It doesn't have any effect on its own.

As for the `quit()` issue, you need to provide more detail, but perhaps this thread might help: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3324